# How to adapt the margins of a page when the height of the header increases?

Tags: java, itext

I am trying to generate pdfs using itext.

I have all my data populated via PdfPtable. 
along with header(of height 15f) and footer(of height 15f) on each page.
sample code --

```
PdfPTable table1 = new PdfPTable(1);
table.setTotalWidth(500);
table.setLockedWidth(true);
cell = new PdfPCell(new phrase("testing 123"));
table.addCell(cell);
table.setSplitLate(false);
```

I have my code(table.setSplitLate(false);) set if the content of my table over flows it goes to next page.

The problem -- I recently received a change request where the headers are going to be 80f or more and depending on that the content\pdf table of the page should be adjusted accordingly.

How do I control the position of the overflown text in the next page. Since it overlaps with the header. please check the screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Unfortunately you don't show the code in which you set the margins of your iText document.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to reserve more space for footers or headers, set the document margins accordingly.

You can do so by using the `Document` constructor with 5 arguments:

```
/**
 * Constructs a new <CODE>Document</CODE> -object.  
 *
 * @param pageSize
 *            the pageSize
 * @param marginLeft
 *            the margin on the left
 * @param marginRight
 *            the margin on the right
 * @param marginTop
 *            the margin on the top
 * @param marginBottom
 *            the margin on the bottom
 */
public Document(Rectangle pageSize, float marginLeft, float marginRight,
        float marginTop, float marginBottom)
```

The other constructors use 36 as default for all margins.

Alternatively you can also set the margins using `setMargins`:

```
/**
 * Sets the margins.
 *
 * @param marginLeft
 *            the margin on the left
 * @param marginRight
 *            the margin on the right
 * @param marginTop
 *            the margin on the top
 * @param marginBottom
 *            the margin on the bottom
 * @return  a <CODE>boolean</CODE>
 */
public boolean setMargins(float marginLeft, float marginRight,
        float marginTop, float marginBottom)
```

This also can be done in mid-document.

In your case,

> a change request where the headers are going to be 80f or more,

you should use that amount plus a bit (depending on the exact position of the header and the desired amount of free space between header and body) for `marginTop`, probably 20.

Comment: Thanks for the reply mkl 
I already had set margins. I was looking for repeated headers on each page and table.setHeaderRows(1); served the purpose